# Bound on second derivative for nonnegative polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials, upper-lower-bounds, approximation-theory

Let $f$ be a univariate polynomials of degree $d$. Assume that:

- $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$
- $f(0) = \varepsilon >0$
- $f'(0) = 0$

My question is the following: **can we deduce lower bounds for $f''(0)$ depending on $d$ and $\varepsilon$?**

This seems reasonable for me, since id the second derivative is too negative, then the first derivative becomes quickly negative and thus $f$ decreases in a neighbourhood of $0$. But then this may contradict the non negativity of $f$.

I tried to exploit the Taylor expansion of $f$, but got no result. I believe that a possible solution would be to use twice the Markov brothers' inequality, that can be stated as follows:

**Theorem** (Markov brothers' inequality). Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $d$. then:
$$\max_{x \in [-t,t]}|f'(x)| \le \frac{2d^2}{2t} \max_{x \in [-t,t]}|f(x)|$$

**Edit**. After the answer of durianice, I restate my question, taking into account also the norm of $f$ (for instance, the max norm of $f$ on [-1,1]):
**can we deduce lower bounds for $f''(0)$ depending on $d$, $\varepsilon$ and $||f||$?**

Clearly, Markov brothers' inequality already gives a bound, but this bound doesn't take into account the special properties of $f$ that I listed above.

Comment: The Markov brothers' inequality works for $f^{(k)}$. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_brothers%27_inequality) and [this article](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/na/people/Alexei/papers/markov.pdf).

Comment: Sure, also imply iterating it. But a straightforward application of the inequality wouldn't take into account the special structure for $f$ that I have (i.e. non negativity, $f(0)= \varepsilon$, $f'(0)=0$)

Answer (score 0):

This is answering the question before the edit, which did not require the bound to depend on $\lVert f \rVert$.

---

Consider $f(x)=ax^4-bx^2+\varepsilon$, where $b>0$ and $a>\frac{b^2}{4\varepsilon}$.
Clearly $f(0)>0$ and $f'(0)=0$.
Also, since the quadratic discriminant $b^2-4a\varepsilon$ is negative,
$f$ has no real root, implying that it is positive on $\mathbb{R}$.
Note that $f''(0)=-2b$, which depends only on some arbitrary $b$.
It then follows that $|f''(0)|$ can be arbitrarily large,
and not bounded by any function depending on $d$ or $\varepsilon$.

Comment: This is clearly a valid answer, but it turns out not to be what I needed: I want also to take into account the norm of $f$ for the bound. I am editing the question accordingly.